# Which is the "correct" 5Y5Y Inflation Expectation on Bloomberg, and what are the differences?

Tags: forward, bloomberg, inflation

When the market talks about 5Y5Y expectation, is it referring to `FWISUS55 Index`, or `G0169 5Y5Y BLC2 Curncy` on Bloomberg?  I suspect it's the first one (e.g. comparing to [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/T5YIFR)), but can't explain why, or what's the difference between the two.

Comment: have you tried asking Bloomberg support (F1 F1 on the terminal)? What did they say?

Comment: The former is the correct one, ie the one that ties back to the Fed's methodology. The latter is Bloomie's estimate (for curves that might not be liquid, and/or traded). So there's a Bloomie Treasury Curve that's inferred, similar but slightly different to the liquid forward-starting swap rate series...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the help desk would have been able to help.  According to the `DES` page, `FWISUS55 Index` is simply `2*USSWIT10 Curncy - USSWIT5 Curncy`. These are zero coupon inflation swap quotes. This is a gross oversimplification. In terms of 5y5y only it works quite well (see the last link below).

Seems `SWIL` (where these inflation swaps are used) is not supported in `FWCM`, where the second ticker comes from. So I guess in terms of inflation swaps, that is as good as you will get.

The second ticker is the `US Treasury Inflation Indexed Curve` - you can load it on GC `YCGT0169 Index GC` to see the constituents `Inflation indexed treasury bonds` on the Table.

FRED is using the latter (treasury securities). However, they transform this relative to nominal swaps. Somewhat similar data can be found on `ILBE` on BBG. You can select `Nominal Bond v Inflation Bond`. More details on what FRED is doing can be found [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/65711/difference-between-5y-breakeven-inflation-and-5y5y-inflation-forward/65713#65713).